# How to join datatable using LINQ

Tags: vb.net, linq, datatable

I have two DataTables:

dt1 - personid, name

dt2 - personid

I want to create a third datatable to include records from dt1 when they are NOT in dt2 using LINQ.  In this case, I can bind the third datatable to a dropdownlist.

any help would be great! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it's in C#, But It could be translated to VB with a little effort

```
dt1.AsEnumerable()
   .Where(o => dt2.Select("personId =" + o["personId"].ToString()).Length == 0);
```

VB:

```
dt1.AsEnumerable()
   .Where(Function(o) 
      dt2.Select("personId =" & o("personId").ToString()).Length = 0)
```

Comment: Thanks! However, I'm very new to LINQ and the online converter does not help.  I have a hard time to figure this out in VB.  It would be great if I can get the answer in VB.  Thanks!

Comment: thanks alot for your help! Will definitely check out the link